# MongoDB Online Archive - Do Partition Fields need to follow the ESR rule?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

From the [official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/online-archive/configure-online-archive/), we can set up partition fields to speed up the performance when using Online Archive.

> The order of fields listed in the path is important in the same way as
> it is in  Compound Indexes . Data in the specified path is partitioned
> first by the value of the first field, and then by the value of the
> next field, and so on. Atlas supports queries on the specified fields
> using the partitions.
>
> For example, suppose you are configuring the online archive for the
> movies collection in the sample_mflix database. If your archived field
> is the released date field, which you moved to the third position,
> your first queried field is title, and your second queried field is
> plot, your partition will look similar to the following:
>
> /title/plot/released Atlas creates partitions first for the title
> field, followed by the plot field, and then the released field. Atlas
> uses the partitions for queries on the following fields:
>
> the title field,
>
> the title field and the plot field,
>
> the title field and the plot field and the released field.
>
> Atlas can also use the partitions to support a query on the title and
> released fields. However, in this case, Atlas would not be as
> efficient in supporting the query as it would be if the query were on
> the title and plot fields only. Partitions are parsed in order; if a
> query omits a particular partition, Atlas is less efficient in making
> use of any partitions that follow that. Since a query on title and
> released omits plot, Atlas uses the title partition more efficiently
> than the released partition to support this query.

Here I simplify the situation for asking. I need to query by:

1. title(eq)/plot(eq)/released(range)
2. title(eq)/released(range)

From the document, `title/plot/released` support `1.` but inefficient to `2.`. If I change it to `released/title/plot`, it seems perfect but violates the ESR rule.

Does Partition Fields need to follow the ESR rule? What is the correct way to solve this requirement? Any deep dive explanations are welcome.